my app.server.module have error this line import { ModuleMapLoaderModule } from '@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader'; Why?
I Created ASP.NET Core with Angular Project in the visual studio 2022. So no codes edited but below line have error called Cannot find module '@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader' or its corresponding type declarations why?
import { ModuleMapLoaderModule } from '@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader';
I updated node.js but still have error
